# Object of arrays into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to change my input which is object of nested arrays:

```
 const bullets = {
  one: [
  [
    1053, 2
  ],
  [
    2222, 7
  ]
],
  two: [
   [
    1053, 4
   ],
   [
    2222, 1
   ]
],
  three: [
   [
    1053, 6
   ],
   [
    2222, 12
   ],
],
};
```

into mapped output, which should look like this:

```
const result = [
  {label: 1053, a: 2, b: 4, c: 6},
  {label: 2222, a: 7, b: 1, c: 12}
]
```

So basically map the values from the input object arrays to the keys in the result. The number of objects is corresponding to the number of unique labels (the "first" values in each subarray). The "second" values in each subarray make the "a", "b" and "c" values assigned to objects with corresponding label.

I tried something like this:

```js
const bullets = {
  one: [
    [
      1053, 2
    ],
    [
      2222, 7
    ]
  ],
  two: [
    [
      1053, 4
    ],
    [
      2222, 1
    ]
  ],
  three: [
    [
      1053, 6
    ],
    [
      2222, 12
    ],
  ],
};
let result = [];

Object.keys(bullets).reduce((p, c) => {
  result.push(bullets[p]
    .map(v => ({
      label: v[0],
      a: v[1],
      b: bullets[c].find(value => value[0] === v[0])[1],
      c: bullets[c].find(value => value[0] === v[0])[1],
    })));
  return c;
});

console.log([].concat(...result));
```

It works for a situation where the input object has only two entries, and I only needed "a" and "b" values in the output, but it's obviously wrong since it results in 4 object instead of two (the "previous" value in reduce is once the first entry, and the second entry during another iteration - similar with "current" value in reduce).

Do you know if that can be achieved the easier way? Maybe some kind of lodash solution? Everything I'm getting here is spaghetti and no exact result. Thanks in advance for tips.

Comment: `find` only returns a single element from the array, so I'm not sure how getting `[1]` from that is working...

Comment: Also, "easier" is an opinion. As you can see from the answer you've already received, it's in the eye of the beholder whether something is "easier" or not... (no offense mean to @CertainPerformance)

Comment: yes, I'm finding a corresponding element which is also an array, so I get the [1] index from that one I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the objects values and check each iteration if there already is an object with the current label. If there is add the value to it's array.

Now instead of having properties like `a`, `b` or `c` i suggest just using an array and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) them into their variables. This way you are not limited to the alphabet or having to define each property before hand.

```js
const bullets = {
  one:   [ [ 1053, 2 ], [ 2222,  7 ] ],
  two:   [ [ 1053, 4 ], [ 2222,  1 ] ],
  three: [ [ 1053, 6 ], [ 2222, 12 ] ]
};

const result = Object.values(bullets).reduce((acc, items) => {
  for(const [key, value] of items) {
    const index = acc.findIndex(({label}) => label === key);
    
    index >= 0
      ? acc[index].values.push(value)
      : acc.push({label: key, values: [value]})
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

// All objects
console.log(result);

// a, b, c
for(const item of result) {
  const [a, b, c] = item.values;
  console.log(a, b, c);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: that will do. I figured - instead of naming the keys of object beforehand (with "a", "b", "b"...) I will just use the object names from the input ("one", "two", "three"). I just need to find a way to populate the object with these dynamic key names. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make an array of the properties to use (eg `a`, `b`, and `c`), then create an object indexed by labels, whose values are the items for the `result` array. Then you can iterate over the input and insert the values as required:

```js
 const bullets = {
  one: [
  [
    1053, 2
  ],
  [
    2222, 7
  ]
],
  two: [
   [
    1053, 4
   ],
   [
    2222, 1
   ]
],
  three: [
   [
    1053, 6
   ],
   [
    2222, 12
   ],
],
};
const properties = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const result = {};
Object.values(bullets).forEach((arr, propIndex) => {
  arr.forEach(([label, val]) => {
    if (!result[label]) result[label] = { label };
    result[label][properties[propIndex]] = val;
  });
});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

```css
  {label: 1053, a: 2, b: 4, c: 6},
  {label: 2222, a: 7, b: 1, c: 12}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is more like C style but it does same job.

```js
const bullets = {
  one: [
  [
    1053, 2
  ],
  [
    2222, 7
  ]
],
  two: [
   [
    1053, 4
   ],
   [
    2222, 1
   ]
],
  three: [
   [
    1053, 6
   ],
   [
    2222, 12
   ],
],
};

var midResult = {}
var results = []
for (const key in bullets) {
const arr = bullets[key];
arr.forEach(elem => {
    if (midResult.hasOwnProperty(elem[0])) {
        midResult[elem[0]].push(elem[1])
    }else{
        midResult[elem[0]]  =[elem[1]]
    }
});
}
for (const key in midResult) {
if (midResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const arr = midResult[key];
    var elem = {}
    elem.label = key
    arr.forEach( (e,i) =>{
        elem[String.fromCharCode(97+i)] = e
    })
    results.push(elem)
}
}
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65006723#comment114929295_65007110) on another answer, you implied that the key names (`'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`) were not important.  This is a technique that reuses the original names (`'one'`, `'two'`, `'three'`) instead.

```js
const transform = (bullets) => Object .entries (Object .entries (bullets)
  .reduce ((a, [name, xs]) => 
    xs .reduce (
      (a, [label, value]) => ({...a, [label]: [...(a [label] || []), [name, value]]}),
      a
    ), {}
  )
) .map (([label, values]) => ({label: Number(label), ...Object .fromEntries (values)}))


const bullets = {one: [[1053, 2], [2222, 7]], two: [[1053, 4], [2222, 1]], three: [[1053, 6], [2222, 12]]}

console .log (
  transform (bullets)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We proceed in a few steps.  The call to `Object .entries (bullets)` yields this:

```js
[
  ["one", [[1053, 2], [2222, 7]]], 
  ["two", [[1053, 4], [2222, 1]]], 
  ["three", [[1053, 6], [2222, 12]]]
]
```

Then the double-reduction turns that into this:

```js
{
  "1053": [["one", 2], ["two", 4], ["three", 6]], 
  "2222": [["one", 7], ["two", 1], ["three", 12]]
}
```

Then we call `Object .entries` again on this result to get

```js
[
  ["1053", [["one", 2], ["two", 4], ["three", 6]]], 
  ["2222", [["one", 7], ["two", 1], ["three", 12]]]
]
```

And finally, with a `map` call using `Object.fromEntries`, we turn that into

```js
[
  {label: 1053, one: 2, two: 4, three: 6, 
  {label: 2222, one: 7, two: 1, three: 12}
]
```

---

If you did want the key transformations, we could supply them in the call, like this:

```js
transform (bullets, {one: 'a', two: 'b', three: 'c'})
```

with only a minor modification to the code.

```js
const transform = (bullets, keys) => Object .entries (Object .entries (bullets)
  .reduce ((a, [name, xs]) => 
    xs .reduce (
      (a, [label, value]) => ({...a, [label]: [...(a [label] || []), [keys[name] || name, value]]}),
      a
    ), {}
  )
) .map (([label, values]) => ({label: Number(label), ...Object .fromEntries (values)}))


const bullets = {one: [[1053, 2], [2222, 7]], two: [[1053, 4], [2222, 1]], three: [[1053, 6], [2222, 12]]}

console .log (
  transform (bullets, {one: 'a', two: 'b', three: 'c'})
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful and gives an awesome insight